# Modified kmeans algorithm returns the wrong answer

Tags: machine-learning, python, k-means, implementation

I am trying to create a kmeans algorithm that is based on the Earth Movers Distance instead of the Euclidean distance. However, when I run it, it just returns the same value for all data points.

The input is an dxn matrix containing all of my n probability distributions.

Here is an example of running the algorithm. The clusters for my data of length 169 should be much more distributed. I've also tried running it for more iterations to no avail.

```
distribution = {}
num_bins = 20
for i in data:
    distribution[i] = np.histogram(data[i], bins = num_bins)[0] / len(data[i])

Z = np.zeros((len(data), num_bins))
for i in range(len(Z)):
    Z[i] = distribution[list(distribution)[i]]
Z = Z.T
ans = k_means_algorithm(Z, 8, k_random)

res = points_to_clusters(Z, ans)
print(res)

[[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.
  1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 3. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.
  1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 4. 1. 0. 4. 1. 1. 1. 4. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.
  1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 4. 2. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0.
  1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 3. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0.
  1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1.
  1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.
  1.]]
```

Here is my code:

````
def k_random(X, k):
   random_idx = np.random.permutation(X.shape[1])
   centroids = X[:, random_idx[:k]]
   return centroids

def points_to_clusters(X, centroids):
    assignment = np.zeros(len(X[0]))
    for i in range(len(X[0])):
        min_dist = 100000000
        for j in range(len(centroids[0])):
            cur_dist = scipy.stats.wasserstein_distance(X[:, i], centroids[:, j])
            #print(cur_dist)
            if cur_dist < min_dist:
                assignment[i] = j
                min_dist = cur_dist
    assignment = np.array([assignment])
    return assignment

def compute_centroids(X, k, cluster_assignments, old_centroids):
    dimensions = X.shape[0]
    centroids = np.zeros((dimensions, k))
    for j in range(k):
        new_centroid = np.mean(X[:, cluster_assignments.squeeze()==j], axis=1)
        if np.isnan(new_centroid).any():
            centroids[:,j] = old_centroids[:,j]
        else:
            centroids[:,j] = np.mean(X[:, cluster_assignments.squeeze()==j], axis=1)
    return centroids


def k_means_algorithm(X, k, random_init, max_iters = 1000, return_obj=False):
    centroids = random_init(X,k)
    cluster_assignments = points_to_clusters(X, centroids)
    new_centroids = compute_centroids(X, k, cluster_assignments, centroids)
    counter = 0
    while not np.array_equal(centroids,new_centroids) and counter < max_iters:
        centroids = new_centroids
        cluster_assignments = points_to_clusters(X, centroids)
        new_centroids = compute_centroids(X, k, cluster_assignments, centroids)
        counter += 1
    return centroids

def proportionally_random_k(X, k):
    centroids = [X[:, np.random.randint(X.shape[1])]]
    for other_centroids in range(k - 1):
        distances = []
        for i in range(X.shape[1]):
            point = X[:, i]
            d = float("inf")
            for j in range(len(centroids)):
                temp_dist = np.linalg.norm(point - centroids[j])
                d = min(d, temp_dist)
            distances.append(d)
        distances = np.array(distances)
        next_centroid = X[:, np.argmax(distances)]
        centroids.append(next_centroid)
        distances = []
    return np.asarray(centroids).T

```
````